# Font-size attribue is broken when displaying any text before <!DOCTYPE…>

Tags: php, html, css, doctype

This may be a dumb question. I'm defining all my styles on an external stylesheet and I'm linking them to my document like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tema.css" />
```

My CSS goes like this:

```css
body {
    background: #333;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans;
}
#Table {
    /* font-size: inherit; */
}
```

And my `<!DOCTYPE>` goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Pretty standard by the way. But why does my CSS style break if I `print` anything *before* the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration on my document?

If I do this:

```html
foo
<!DOCTYPE … >
<html>
    <table id="Table">…</table>
</html>
```

The `font-size` attribute of my table gets broken and all the text within it is rendered with the default `font-size` of my browser (12 pt), but **only** the text that is **inside** the table (I'm yet to find another issues, this is the only one I've noticed so far), and only if I don't set an specific `font-size` for the table, either `10pt` directly or `inherit`:

[image: Table example 1]

However, if I do this (put the `<!DOCTYPE>` *before* the echoing):

```html
<!DOCTYPE … >
foo
<html>
    <table id="Table">…</table>
</html>
```

Or this (set an specific `font-size` for the table, even when the `<!DOCTYPE>` is *after* the echoed text):

```css
body {
    …
}
#Table {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Everything seems to work fine:

[image: Table example 2]

The question is: Why? Has this happened to someone else? Is this a bug? should I report it?

Here's the [test document](http://pastebin.com/wHxx4kT0) on pastebin so you can play with it.

**Note**:

This happens on Google Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera, Midori and even my android's built-in browser.

I'm echoing that text only for debugging purposes, so it's not that necessary, and I can leave the `<!DOCTYPE>` at the top but it just feels wrong to have it there, it's just that I can't find any information of this behaviour that is related to the position of the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration.

Comment: For the record, this isn't PHP. This behaviour happens with any HTML document.

Comment: @Undeterminant that's right, let me update the information.

Comment: Avoid having any output above the doctype—it's as simple as that.

Comment: For debugging purposes, put the text after the start of the `body` element (possibly in an HTML comment, if it does not need to be visible on the page, just in HTML source).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela it's because the text is originally being echoed from within a php clause that is on top of the document. I just find it easier to have it printed at the top than to have to open the code explorer every time i need to see some debugging information.

Comment: @ralph.m I understand, it's just that I didn't know about the quirks mode and since this was just for debugging purposes it's not a real issue that I should worry about. I state that at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug.

Having anything before `DOCTYPE` switch rendering engine in browsers to quirks mode and makes them to behave like IE5 (well, sort of).

So, the best solution is always output `DOCTYPE` before anything else.

In your case the problem is in

> Don't inhertit font properties into tables except for font-family.

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_Quirks_Mode_Behavior

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

Comment: This: *Don't inhertit font properties into tables except for font-family.* on [Mozilla Quirks Mode Behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_Quirks_Mode_Behavior) is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't output anything before `<!DOCTYPE>`. The Doctype should be the absolute first thing the browser sees in the document, as it uses the doctype to figure out how to render the page.

The web is built on standards and when the HTML is fundamentally broken, the browser switches over to Quirks Mode.

Comment: As I stated on the question, it was just for debugging purposes so it was not causing me issues of any kind, it's just that I found that behaviour strange. But now I know it's not anything weird, just the *quirks mode*.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any user-readable or browser-interpreted text before the DOCTYPE declaration, because it specifies the type of content you want to use in your document. The solution is simply to avoid doing that. The only text allowed before the DOCTYPE declaration is the one read solely by the server side - for example PHP code, JSP snipplets and so on..

Comment: Thank you, now I'm aware of that. It was not causing me real trouble since it was for debugging purposes only (a makeshift approach for debugging indeed), but I'll make sure I won't do that.